# How to write a Unit test with asynchronous lambda?

Tags: android, unit-testing

Please help me write the test. I need to catch the onComplete function call with false, but it's asynchronous and I can't do it.

```
fun openDoor(intercomId: Int, onComplete: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val statusResponse: StatusResponseData?
        try {
            statusResponse = apiRepository.openAnyIntercomByJwt(intercomId.toString())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                onComplete(false)
            }
            return@launch
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            onComplete(statusResponse?.status != null && statusResponse.status == "ok")
        }
    }
}
```

my test:

```
@Test
fun `getIntercomState and failed`() {
    val viewModel = DeepLinkViewModel(apiRepository)
    coEvery { apiRepository.getIntercomState(any()) } returns null

    var result = true
    runTest {

        viewModel.getIntercomState("test") {
            result = it
        }
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(false, result)
}
```

Comment: Put the assert inside the runTest Block. And did you create a Dispatcher Rule as show here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test  (look for MainDispatcherRule)